# Zenity windows are no longer the same size

Tags: zenity

Lately, I have been using zenity with a progress window, and opening questions with the same size on top of the progress window, to hide it. With Ubuntu 14.04, they were exactly the same size, and it worked perfectly. Now, with Ubuntu 16.04, they are *not* the same size, as shown below.

In case you were wondering, here is a command that shows what I am talking about, however I don't use zenity quite like the example.

```
zenity --list --height 400 --width 400 --column "I'm skinnier." --title "zenity --list" | zenity --progress --width 400 --text "I'm fatter" --title "zenity --progress" --height 400
```

So, is there a way to make them the same size?

Alternatively, I could just hide the progress window, but *how* would I do it?

Screenshot on Ubuntu 16.04:

[image: Screenshot on 16.04]

Screenshot on Ubuntu 14.04:

[image: Screenshot on 14.04]

Comment: so you were using `zenity --progress` and then covering it with `zenity --list` ? is that what you're saying ?

Comment: Yes, I am covering the progress window. I'm showing the progress window standalone on some occasions, e.g. connecting to server.